# Provide visual cues for indent level in vim

Tags: vim, indentation, vim-syntax-highlighting

I've used `listchars` to mark certain whitespace characters for visual identification, but I am wondering if there is a similar feature to visually mark the indentation level in vim.  Something like a visible marker for a potential fold-line.  Something like this:

```
#/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3 ; do
.   if [ true ] ; then
.   .   echo "there is an unobtrusive"
.   .   echo "dot character that marks"
.   .   echo "the indentation level."
.   fi
done
```

I'll bet an imaginative use of `colorcolumn` could create this, but maybe there is a pre-canned vim script that does this already.

Comment: https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plugins that implement this:

- [vim indent guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides)
- [indentLine](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine)